# SUBCONSULTAS EN MONGO

Tags: mongodb, subconsultas, colecciones

Buen día, muchachos estoy iniciando en este mundo de mongo y tengo un problema para hacer una subconsulta. Necesito saber que empleados tienen un salario mayor al promedio de todos los salarios de la colección:

COLECCIÓN (6 docs):

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e80"),
        "CEDULA" : "85513143",
        "NOMBRE" : "Blaze",
        "APELLIDO" : "Blake",
        "EDAD" : 21,
        "SALARIO" : 1581549
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e81"),
        "CEDULA" : "79641828",
        "NOMBRE" : "Felix",
        "APELLIDO" : "Burns",
        "EDAD" : 24,
        "SALARIO" : 1333959
}


{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e82"),
        "CEDULA" : "10256656",
        "NOMBRE" : "Denton",
        "APELLIDO" : "Armstrong",
        "EDAD" : 19,
        "SALARIO" : 1891820
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e83"),
        "CEDULA" : "23783746",
        "NOMBRE" : "Gemma",
        "APELLIDO" : "Calderon",
        "EDAD" : 25,
        "SALARIO" : 1401654
}


{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e84"),
        "CEDULA" : "34925626",
        "NOMBRE" : "Tanek",
        "APELLIDO" : "Faulkner",
        "EDAD" : 24,
        "SALARIO" : 1254378
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("608e38559928adbc8b614e8c"),
        "CEDULA" : "10698942",
        "NOMBRE" : "Yuli",
        "APELLIDO" : "Bray",
        "EDAD" : 22,
        "SALARIO" : 1693303
}
```

Para este caso el promedio de todos los salarios es: 1526111.

Y quiero que la consulta me arroje que los empleados que tienen un salario mayor a ese promedio son:

```
    "NOMBRE" : "Yuli", "SALARIO" : 1693303
    "NOMBRE" : "Denton",  "SALARIO" : 1891820
    "NOMBRE" : "Blaze", "SALARIO" : 1581549
```

Aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      SALARIO: {
        $gt: {
          db.test.aggregate([
            {
              $group: {
                _id:null,
                promedio: {
                  $avg: "$SALARIO"
                }
              }
            }
          ])
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "NOMBRE": "$NOMBRE",
        "SALARIO": "$SALARIO"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué ha intentado? código...

Comment: db.test.aggregate([{$match:{SALARIO:{ $gt:{db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, promedio: {$avg:"$SALARIO"} } }])}}}},{$group:{_id: {"NOMBRE":"$NOMBRE", "SALARIO":"$SALARIO"}}}])

Comment: Además de dar formato a los datos, al editar la pregunta, quité la etiqueta SQL, que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Sugiero que agregues una explicación o código de lo que has intentado o qué dificultad tienes para conseguir el resultado; de otra manera, la pregunta podría no ser bien recibida por la comunidad. Un saludo.

Comment: db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, promedio: {$avg:"$SALARIO"} } }]), con esta parte la consulta lo que hago es calcular el promedio de todos de la colección, esta parte me funciona bien me arroja como resultado: 1526111. Ahora lo que yo intento hacer es de los empleados de la colección me muestre aquellos empleados que tienen un salario mayor que ese promedio, lo estoy intentado hacer con un match pero no funciona, yo sé que puedo  colocar manualmente el valor del promedio: SALARIO:{ $gt:1526111} y funciona la consulta, pero estoy intentado que todo esto se haga mediante una subconsulta

Comment: Si pudieras agregar el pipeline de agregación a la pregunta, saludos

Comment: yo tengo entendido que el pipeline es el match que uno hace en la consulta, no sé si estoy equivocado...
db.test.aggregate([{$match:{SALARIO:{ $gt:{db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, promedio: {$avg:"$SALARIO"} } }])}}}}

Comment: Por favor, **edita** tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit]. Agrega todo eso que pusiste en comentarios en la pregunta. Intentar leer el código en el comentario es un esfuerzo inútil. Otros usuarios simplemente lo pasan por alto. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea filtrar una serie de documentos en base a una condición calculada, es decir, se debe calcular un valor promedio a partir de los documentos de la colección y en base a dicho resultado, filtrar sólo aquellos que cumplan una condición al compararse contra dicho valor, todo esto usando un [proceso de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) sobre una colección de una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/).

El problema con tu agregación es que esto:

```js
$gt: {
  db.test.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id:null,
        promedio: {
          $avg: "$SALARIO"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
}
```

No es una [exprsión de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions) válida en MongoDB, ya que `db.collection.aggregate` no forma parte de las mismas.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Uno de los desafíos principales de este problema particular, es obtener el valor promedio y filtrar al mismo tiempo. Usualmente se usan 2 consultas por separado, la primera con el fin de obtener el promedio y la segunda para filtrar los datos. Sin embargo, podemos hacer ambas cosas a la vez usando un proceso de agregación, mediante diferentes etapas.

Una forma de hacerlo sería calcular el valor promedio agrupando los datos, sin embargo esto devuelve un sólo valor, debemos a la vez almacenar los datos de cada documento para poder trabajar con los mismos en las siguientes etapas.

Para calcular el valor promedio de un campo en documentos de una colección usaremos una etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) junto con los operadores [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) y [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). El operador `$avg` nos permite calcular un promedio de un conjunto de valores numéricos, y el operador `$push` nos servirá para almacenar en un campo todos los datos relevantes de los documentos de la colección en una lista o Array:

```js
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "promedio": {
      "$avg": "$SALARIO"
    },
    "datos": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "cedula": "$CEDULA",
        "nombre": "$NOMBRE",
        "salario": "$SALARIO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En la etapa `$group` anterior, hemos agrupado usando un campo `_id` como `null`, hemos calculado el promedio del campo `salario` de cada documento y a la vez hemos salvado la información de cada documento en una lista cuyo nombre es `datos`.

Ahora es fácil filtrar los datos de la lista, ya que tenemos el valor del promedio que usaremos para realizar dicho filtrado. Para ello nos apoyaremos en una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) junto con el operador de filtrado [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), el cual recibe una lista de elementos, asigna un identificador para cada elemento de la lista y realiza la comparación requerida, devolviendo sólo aquellos documentos de la lista que superen el filtro. Para realizar la comparación usaremos el operador [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/).

```js
{
  "$project": {
    "filtrados": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$datos",
        "as": "elem",
        "cond": {
          "$gte": [
            "$$elem.salario",
            "$promedio"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En la etapa `$project` anterior hemos volcado el resultado del proceso de filtrado en un campo de tipo Array llamado `filtrados`. Notemos que el operador `$filter` usa un nombre de variable temporal para cada elemento de la lista: `elem`. Dicha variable se usa en la condición de filtro usando doble signo `$` como en:

```js
"cond": {
  "$gte": [
    "$$elem.salario", // <- nombre de variable para referirse a cada elemento de la lista
    "$promedio"
  ]
}
```

La comparación `$gte` la hacemos contra el campo `promedio` que habíamos calculado en la etapa `$group` anterior.

Ahora tenemos todos los documentos que superan el filtro en un campo llamado `filtrados`, para sacarlos de allí debemos *romper* esta lista o Array, y para ello usaremos una etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) sobre dicho campo:

```js
{
  "$unwind": "$filtrados"
}
```

Ahora tendremos una serie de documentos que contendrá solo un campo llamado `_id` y un campo llamado `filtrados`.

Como no deseamos el valor `_id: null` que creamos en la etapa de agrupación, podemos tranquilamente reemplazar todo el documento con el valor del campo `filtrados`. Esto para documento que tenemos hasta hora. Para ello nos apoyaremos en una etapa [`replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) que nos va permitir hacer precisamente lo que deseamos:

```js
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$filtrados"
  }
}
```

De esta forma, ahora la salida será una lista de documentos filtrados según la condición de que el campo `salario` sea mayor o igual al promedio del valor calculado para todos los documentos.

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/37vc8t5Iiln) puedes ver un ejemplo de todo el código funcionando. Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.